# is there a way to have an optional argument and subparsers for argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to have my program handle commands  (`gui`, `daemon`...)  via subparsers, but also handle one optional positional `url` argument. The optional argument would only be used when the OS calls my program because the user clicked on some URI associated with my program.

This is a simplified example of what I would like to achieve:

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()


parser.add_argument("url", nargs="?")

# global options
parser.add_argument("--password")
parser.add_argument("--verbose", action="store_true")

# subparser
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest="cmd", help='sub-command help')

gui_parser = subparsers.add_parser("gui")
gui_parser.add_argument("--testnet", action="store_true")


daemon_parser = subparsers.add_parser("daemon")
daemon_parser.add_argument("subcommand", nargs="?", help="start, stop, status or commands added by plugins")
daemon_parser.add_argument("subargs", nargs="*",  metavar="arg", help="additional arguments (used by plugins)")


url = 'ecash:sdfqsdf?amount=1337.42&message="monthly payment to supplier #42"'

args = parser.parse_args([url])
print(args.url, args.cmd, args.verbose, args.password)

args = parser.parse_args(["--verbose", url])
print(args.url, args.cmd, args.verbose, args.password)

args = parser.parse_args(["--verbose", "--password", "123", "gui", "--testnet"])
print(args.url, args.password, args.cmd, args.testnet)

args = parser.parse_args(["daemon", "start"])
print(args.url, args.password, args.cmd, args.subcommand)

args = parser.parse_args(["daemon", "show_label", "id00021"])
print(args.url, args.password, args.cmd, args.subcommand, args.subargs)
```

Unfortunately the optional `url` argument does not seem to work:

```
$ python test.py
usage: test.py [-h] [--password PASSWORD] [--verbose] [url] {gui,daemon} ...
test.py: error: argument cmd: invalid choice: 'ecash:sdfqsdf?amount=1337.42&message="monthly payment to supplier #42"' (choose from 'gui', 'daemon')
```

Is there a way to do that, or are subparsers incompatible with additional arbitrary positional arguments?

Comment: I'd suspect that the `nargs='?'` is probably screwing with it; subparsers are supposed to be optional, but having a positional optional argument to go with the optional subparser is probably beyond `argparse`'s heuristic capabilities. Have you tried just making a third sub-command for the OS to use that itself takes a non-optional `url` positional argument?

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm not sure the OS will be able to call my application via the subcommand when associating that `ecash:...`  mimetype with my application. AFAIK it will always call it like this `my_program <URI>`

Comment: To the main parser, the subparsers argument is a positional. So another positional with `?` will not play well with it.  `positionals` are parsed by position, not by value..  Regular flagged arguments are better..

Comment: @ShadowRanger, the subparsers is a positional with choices.  It isn't required in the sense that the parser won't complain if there isn't one.  But in this context it is greedy, like a regular positional.

Comment: @hpaulj: Yeah, I was assuming that's how it works. The weirder you get with `argparse`, the more likely you are to run into edge cases like this.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, the fact that subparsers is not required is a bit of developmental error.  Originally is was required, But with a change in how required items were checked, it fell through the cracks. Even so it required a couple of patches to error messages correct.  As a result it's a bit of an odd duck

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the optional URL and the sub commands are mutually exclusive, based on your examples. Here is one way to approach this problem: I would parse the command line arguments in 2 passes. The first will just parse out the url or sub command. The next pass will parse the remainder.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse


def parse_command_line(command_line=None):
    # Pass 1: parse --password, --verbose, (url or cmd)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--password")
    parser.add_argument("--verbose", action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument("cmd")
    options, remainder = parser.parse_known_args(command_line)

    # Pass 2: parse the remainder base on gui, daemon, or URL
    if options.cmd == "gui":
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument("--testnet", action="store_true")
        parser.parse_args(remainder, options)
    elif options.cmd == "daemon":
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument(
            "subcommand",
            nargs="?",
            help="start, stop, status or commands added by plugins",
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            "subargs",
            nargs="*",
            metavar="arg",
            help="additional arguments (used by plugins)",
        )
        parser.parse_args(remainder, options)
    else:
        # Assume cmd is a URL
        options.url = options.cmd
        options.cmd = "url"
    return options


def tryout(command_line):
    print(f"\n# {command_line}")
    options = parse_command_line(command_line)
    print(options)


url = 'ecash:sdfqsdf?amount=1337.42&message="monthly payment to supplier #42"'
tryout([url])
tryout(["--verbose", url])
tryout(["--verbose", "--password", "123", "gui", "--testnet"])
tryout(["daemon", "start"])
tryout(["daemon", "show_label", "id00021"])
```

Output:

```
# ['ecash:sdfqsdf?amount=1337.42&message="monthly payment to supplier #42"']
Namespace(password=None, verbose=False, cmd='url', url='ecash:sdfqsdf?amount=1337.42&message="monthly payment to supplier #42"')

# ['--verbose', 'ecash:sdfqsdf?amount=1337.42&message="monthly payment to supplier #42"']
Namespace(password=None, verbose=True, cmd='url', url='ecash:sdfqsdf?amount=1337.42&message="monthly payment to supplier #42"')

# ['--verbose', '--password', '123', 'gui', '--testnet']
Namespace(password='123', verbose=True, cmd='gui', testnet=True)

# ['daemon', 'start']
Namespace(password=None, verbose=False, cmd='daemon', subcommand='start', subargs=[])

# ['daemon', 'show_label', 'id00021']
Namespace(password=None, verbose=False, cmd='daemon', subcommand='show_label', subargs=['id00021'])
```

#### Notes

- When calling `parse_command_line`, if the caller does not specify a `command_line`, then `sys.argv[1:]` will be used.
- If URL is not mutually exclusive to the sub commands (gui, daemon), then you might want to make it "--url" instead of "url"